# Symfony logout handler, differentiate between button hit and session expiration

Tags: php, symfony

I got my custom logout handler which is the following:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutHandlerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

class LogoutListener implements LogoutHandlerInterface
{
protected $securityContext;
protected $entityManager;
protected $logger;

public function __construct(TokenStorage $securityContext, EntityManager $entityManager, $logger)
{
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function logout(Request $Request, Response $Response, TokenInterface $Token)
{
    $em = $this->entityManager;
    $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    $em->getConnection()->executeUpdate("UPDATE subjects SET edited_by = NULL
                  WHERE edited_by=" . $user->getId());

    $this->logger->makelog(1, 'Выход из системы');
}
```

Here I log into a file all logout actions. Now I need to differentiate between user logout upon button hit, and session expiration. Any ideas how to do that? What service should I implement. Now logout upon session expiration is simply handled in config.yml

```
session:
    save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    cookie_lifetime: 3600
    gc_maxlifetime: 3600
```